# How to use Power Shell cmdlets with batch file?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, cmdlets, batch

I have bit interesting requirements. My client want to develop the Sharepoint 2010 administration UI from Java application. So I suggest him to user Sharepoint web services. As we all know its good to use. but he want to perform this on command based. So I suggest to user of batch files with Powershell cmdlets. I am not sure with this architecture. but can somebody focus me up , how to use power shell commands (cmdlets) with the bat file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute them like any other script which you schedule in your servers Task Scheduler (if that is what you want to do on a regular basis). First, build your powershell script as you usually do and place the file in an appropriate folder. Then build your bat-file calling the powershell script - like this:

```
powershell .\test.ps1 arg1
```

You can have multiple argument while calling the script as long as you handle them in your script.

If you need to write .bat-files using powershell, you can use the Out-File command, well described in the article [Using the Out-File Cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176924.aspx). Like the following:

```
Get-Process | Out-File c:\scripts\test.txt
```

More to read: [Use bat to start Powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804751/use-bat-to-start-powershell-script)

Comment: Thanks Benny, In fact This is the way how to execute the .bat file with Power shell... I need how to write bat file with sharepoint cmdlets .. any example ?

Comment: @RedSwan Isn't it just to make a standard .txt file with the extention .bat from a regular File writing as in [Using the Out-File Cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176924.aspx)? That's what I would do.

Comment: Don't forget that by default PowerShell won't allow execution of scripts. To ensure that you don't experience problems add the parameter '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass' to the powershell command line so that the policy is temporarily disabled for this invocation.

Comment: I don't know. but I think you are right.